# Take number from string value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have a text value that has a number and that number start with zero. For example `"User number 054321"` and I take this number from the text by the code below.

```
var phonenumber = "054321"

let myNumber = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("".join(phonenumber.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)))

println(myNumber) //54321
```

My issue is it never takes the first number which start with 0 value but it accept all other number. So please where would be my issue?

Comment: the magic of a numeric values is that the `001`, `00001` or `01` are the same number – the number `1`; if you want to keep the entire phone number (with the leading zeros, number sings or plus symbol) as it was typed, you have to keep as string.

Comment: @holex Ok. So than I've to write it as "0(myNumber!)" ?? Or is there better way?

Comment: I think the better way is __not to convert it__ to numeric values at all, because the `054321`, `004454321` or `+4454321` would mean _exact_ same phone number in e.g. UK. think about what you would get as output when you start to convert them to numeric values and forcibly add the leading zero later... you will get `04454321` and `054321`, which are two completely different phone-numbers, and you can be sure that one of them is entirely _invalid_, while the original inputs were _valid_.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information @holex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number can't start with 0. Or at least, will never be displayed with a 0 as a first character. `054321 = 54321 = 0000000000054321` but at the end, it's still `54321`.

Anyway, a phone number should not be stored as a number but as a string, since it may start with a "0" or with a "+".

**TL;DR: If you want to keep your 0 at the beginning of the number, store it as a string.**

Comment: Ok. So than I've to write it as "0\(myNumber!)" ?? Or is there better way?

Comment: Just forget that's a number and handle it as a string. It's a phone number = it's a string. You might have issues if you start altering user provided phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to fetch `Int` from `String`:

```
let myString : String = "123"
let myInt: Int? = myString.toInt()

if myInt != nil {
    println(myInt)
}
```

Or if you are using Swift 2:

```
let myInt: Int? = Int(myString)
```